# Name of painting by Leonara Carrington

Tags: painting

Can anyone tell me the name of this painting? It's by Leonara Carrington but I can't find the name anywhere.
(http://payload120.cargocollective.com/1/1/60195/4718266/leonora%20carrington1.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are a site for applying art, not discussion of existing art. Identification of art pieces is off topic here. For the related discussion, please see [this](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302/identify-this-painting-questions) meta post.

Comment: use google images search... paste the url of the source. the answer is immediate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could only find a couple of places where it was named ([here](http://curiator.com/art/leonora-carrington/el-recital-de-los-suenos), which is pulling the information from [here](http://thingsthatquickentheheart.blogspot.fr/2011/05/leonora-carrington-dissolved-into-her.html) and [here](http://ccadvisualculture.blogspot.com/2015/01/surrealism.html)), and they both refer to it as "El recital de los sueños." But, in both of those cases the image link is broken, and I would expect to find more pictures available once I searched on the exact image name, but there weren't many, so I am not sure this information is correct.

I also found a sculpture that seems related:
[image]